# Is it possible to make datagridview look like spss environment

Tags: c#, vb.net

How do I make my **datagridview** rows look like **spss** datagrid.
In **spss** if you dont enter numbers in cells the row show inactive.

**Example:**
https://psychwire.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/spss_base.png

From 1 to 10 rows are active from 11 to ... are not active

**Any suggestions**, is it possible to do that with **datagridview**

Comment: Yes, you can. Each Column of a DataGridView can be `Enabled`, `Read-Only`, `Frozen`, `Visible` or not. The aspect of the Control is completely customizable, to the Cell level. So is of course the color of the grid, which is property that applies to all Cells. The Headers, both Row Header and Column Header can be painted as required.

Comment: So how to do that( if cell is null row will be disabled and if I put number it will be enabled)

Comment: We're not here to teach you the basics from scratch. This site is for things that you can't find out on your own, not for things that you can't be bothered to work out. If you want to customise a `DataGridView` then make the effort to find out how to do that. Read the documentation for the class and related types to see what can be done. Experiment a bit to see if things work the way you think based on your research. Only post here when you encounter an actual issue. Not knowing how to do something is not an issue because the solution is to read how to do it.

Comment: If I can do it my self why ask for help, I m not trying to chang colour, I am trying to disable rows with null to prevent calculations errors and counts errors, and I didn't find any solution for the, that why I ask for help

Answer (score 0):

write a for loop stating from the 10 and condition will be your datagridview rows count.
Ex:

```
for(Int i=10;i<mydataGridView.Rows.Count-1;i++)
{
   mydataGridView[i].ReadOnly = true;
}
```

Comment: But if I delete cas number 10 then 10 will be disabled automatically and the rest from 1 to 9 stay enable?

Comment: You need to check it and program is as suitable. I just show you a way